# Where can I find a VAT API?

Tags: php, jquery, api, curl

Where I'm from I don't have to do VAT (Value Added Tax). But a project I'm doing requires its input to legally complete a transaction.

Where can I find an API where I can get relevant info (address, company name, etc) from a VAT tax number? I want to use it to auto-populate a form since there is no better way to scare away a customer than to make him work.

Comment: By *VAT tax*, you mean the *value added tax tax*, right? According to which laws should the VAT tax be calculated?

Comment: Which region(s) of the world do you want this to work for? Does your "VAT Tax" include US Sales Tax, for example? I doubt you'll find any one solution that works for every country's VAT registry.

Comment: Hi and thank you. Here is an excerpt directly from the project file: "The English word, used in Europe is VAT
The Dutch translation of VAT is BTW
In Australia and New Zealand, they call VAT GST " ... so we're talking these regions. I'm not sure the specifics of the abbreviation, but here is a typical formatted vat tax number, which should answer the question of it's purpose "NL174904241B0"

Comment: Well, for Europe you may want to start at the [Wikipedia entry for VAT ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VAT_identification_number), which suggests they can be "verified online at the [EU's official VIES website](http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/vieshome.do)", so you may want to see if that site has an API. I very much doubt that would work for Australia and New Zealand, though.

Comment: Thanks - I had been there and did not find an API - usually posting happens after a few hours googling.

Comment: You may have needed to spend a few more hours Googling. [Here's the answer in their FAQ that points to their SOAP-based API](http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/faq.html#item_16). And [here's](http://nephics.com/euvat) someone who provides a faster, commercial, layer on top of it that returns JSON if you (sensibly) don't like SOAP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [VIES](http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/vieshome.do) as mentioned in the comments, has an API. And I have implemented exactly what you asked for, mainly for the same reason. AND its' php. Here you go:

```
class VatValidator {

const validVatId = 'valid';
const invalidVatId = 'invalid';

/**
 *
 * The european commission (ec) provides a validation database for VAT Id's, which can be accessed via WSDL.
 * We check the given VAT against that Database.
 *
 * Actually that is more reliable than any captcha !!!
 *
 *  * only companies have one
 *  * the code can not be "brute forced"
 *  * simple mass requests can be cut off easily
 *
 * @param String $requestedVatId entire VAT Id including country code
 * @param string $company optional Company Name
 * @param string $city optional company city
 * @return Multiple false on error, String self::validVatId or String self::invalidVatId according to state.
 */
public static function validateVATID($requestedVatId, $company=null, $city=null)
{
    $ret = false;
    $ecUrl = "http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl";
    $vatid = str_replace(array(' ', '.', '-', ',', ', '), '', trim($requestedVatId));
    $cc = substr($vatid, 0, 2);
    $vn = substr($vatid, 2);
    $client = new SoapClient($ecUrl);

    if($client)
    {
        $params = array('countryCode' => $cc,
                        'vatNumber' => $vn,
        );

        /*
         * simple request only since we do not get any further information anyway.
         *
         * with $r = $client->checkVatApprox($params);
         * we could:
         *
                    'requesterCountryCode' => 'XXX',
                    'requesterVatNumber' => 'XXX' // Own ID!!

        if ( !empty($company) )
            $params['traderName'] = $company;
        if ( !empty($city) )
            $params['traderCity'] = $city;

        $params["traderCompanyType"] = 1;
        $params["traderStreet"] = 'xyz';
        $params["traderPostcode"] = '1234';
        */

        try
        {
            //$r = $client->checkVatApprox($params);
            $r = $client->checkVat($params);
            if($r->valid == true)
            {
                logMessage(Constants::$debug, 'valid: ' . $vatid);
                $ret = self::validVatId;
            }
            else
            {
                logMessage(Constants::$debug, 'invalid: ' . $vatid);
                $ret = self::invalidVatId;
            }

            // This foreach shows every single line of the returned information
            //              foreach($r as $k=>$prop)
            //              {
            //                  logMessage(Constants::$debug, $k.': '.$prop);
            //              }
            //logMessage(Constants::$debug, print_r($r, true));

        } catch(SoapFault $e) {
           logMessage(Constants::$debug, 'Error, see message: '.$e->faultstring);
           $ret = $e->faultstring;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        logMessage(Constants::$debug, 'cannot connect to ' . $ecUrl);
        $ret = 'CONNECTERROR';
    }
    return $ret;
}
}
```

the "XXX" in the code may be your own VAT ID, in order to prevent a bit frauding by just putting in your own ID ...

Comment: This is beautiful - I would not have expected that! I'm still perplexed where you came up with this: http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl Nonetheless, very grateful! Thank you!

Comment: what about company name check? This tool only checks if the number is a valid number not if the customer who offers you this number is from that company. How can I check if a vat reg number fits a given company name?

Comment: @Ello AFAIK this tool also can check for a given company, If the company name is provided in the request, it will check that. It will not disclose any information but give you a "valid" or "not valid"